# Return file from web-api cause error "Could not find file"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to return file from my web api and I got `System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not find file`.

I can read the byte array like this: `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(csvPath);`

but when I am returning file with the same path like this: `return File(csvPath, "text/csv", "data.csv");`

It's throwing `System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not find file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be that [`File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_String_System_String_System_String_) accepts a `virtualPath` as a path, which is different from a normal path. Read [this blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths) to find out more about different types of paths in ASP.NET, or you can just use a different overload that accepts a file stream as a parameter: [`File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_IO_Stream_System_String_System_String_).

For example:

```
var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(csvPath);
return File(stream, "text/csv", "data.csv");
```

Comment: Helped in my case, thanks. I also tried to input normal path, from DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()